# openCV in Objective-C for XCode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

I want to use openCV for my project. The steps that I followed are:

1) Downloaded openCV iOS Framework 2.4.11 from here:http://opencv.org/downloads.html

2) Dragged and dropped openCV2 framework after extracting it from the downloaded zip file.

3) Opened an Objective-C iOS app project in XCode, where I created a PrefixHeader.pch file. In the build settings, I paste the location of .pch and keep Precompile Prefix Header to 'No'

I write the following code inside .pch file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

4) In Viewcontroller.m, I do the following:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "opencv2/highgui/ios.h"
```

5) I rename ViewController.m to .mm so that I can make it compatible with C++ of openCV. Then I place my openCV code as follows:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lena.png"];

// Convert UIImage* to cv::Mat
UIImageToMat(image, cvImage);

if (0)
{

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"lena" ofType:@"png"];
    // Create file handle
    NSFileHandle* handle =
    [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
    // Read content of the file
    NSData* data = [handle readDataToEndOfFile];
    // Decode image from the data buffer
    cvImage = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, [data length], CV_8UC1,
                                   (void*)data.bytes),
                           CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
}

if (0)
{
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    // Decode image from the data buffer
    cvImage = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, [data length], CV_8UC1,
                                   (void*)data.bytes),
                           CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
}

if (!cvImage.empty())
{
    cv::Mat gray;
    // Convert the image to grayscale
    cv::cvtColor(cvImage, gray, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
    // Apply Gaussian filter to remove small edges
    cv::GaussianBlur(gray, gray,
                     cv::Size(5, 5), 1.2, 1.2);
    // Calculate edges with Canny
    cv::Mat edges;
    cv::Canny(gray, edges, 0, 50);
    // Fill image with white color
    cvImage.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));
    // Change color on edges
    cvImage.setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 128, 255, 255), edges);
    // Convert cv::Mat to UIImage* and show the resulting image
    imageView.image = MatToUIImage(cvImage);
```

When I build the project, it gives me an error of build not properly linked as well as Use of undeclared identifier 'cvImage'. Can someone give a step-by-step procedure of running an opencv2 framework for iOS app.

Comment: What is your build arguments? (And linker flags?)

Comment: Actually I solved the problem. It was a missing link in my ViewController.h. However, an error I am facing is that it can not read an JPEG file and some png files are undetected.

Comment: Are you currently compiling for objc or c++? Also what is the backend for image loading that you are using for opencv? (ffmpeg?)

Comment: I am using UIImage to Mat Conversion in openCV.

    void UIImageToMat(const UIImage* image,
                         cv::Mat& m, bool alphaExist = false);

Comment: this is not working